# How can we include a form in _layout?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I currently have a _layout.cshtml used by every page of my website.
I need to put a form on each page displayed as a popin.
So, i created a new PartialView (the content of my form) with its corresponding ViewModel and called it in _layout.cshtml.

However, i have a model conflict between ViewModels of pages using the layout and the ViewModel used by the new form (since we can't have directly two models for the same view).

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'XXX', but this
>   dictionary requires a model item of type 'YYY'.

How can we include a form in _layout without this conflict ?

Comment: how did you call PartialView in your _layout.cshtml?

Comment: @{ Html.RenderPartial("_Partner"); }

Comment: try this `@Html.Partial("_Partner")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following has worked for me with a sidebar on every page.

1. Create a controller for your partial view
2. In that controller, create a method for the view you want to return, and be sure to use the [ChildActionOnly] filter

   ```
   public class PartialController : Controller
   {
       [ChildActionOnly]
       public PartialViewResult Alerts()
       {

           return PartialView("Alerts", messages);
       }
   }
   ```
3. In your _layout view, you'll have the following:

   ```
   @Html.Action("Alerts", "Partial")
   ```

   (instead of @Html.RenderPartial or @Html.Partial)
4. It sounds like you already have what you need for the view.

I have not used this with a form, but it should work similarly. Hope this helps.

Comment: To pass by the controller with RenderAction/Action was the good idea :-) Thank you !